# How to remove desc messages from rspec when using thor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, thor

Now I am using [thor](http://whatisthor.com/) in a rails project.

I wrote these codes:

lib/tasks/my_task.rb

```
require 'thor'

module Tasks
  class MyTask < Thor
    desc 'My Batch', 'This is my awesome batch'
    option :date
    def execute(type)
      # do_something
    end
  end
end

Tasks::MyTask.start(ARGV)
```

spec/lib/tasks/my_task_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Test my task' do
  context 'With date option' do
    before do
      @option = { date: '20150903' }
    end

    it 'Can insert to db' do
      expect do
        Tasks::MyTask.new.invoke(:execute, ['commit'], @option)
      end.to change(ProductTable, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is when I run `bundle exec rspec`, it showed:

```
Run options: exclude {:heavy=>true}
..................................................................................................................................................................................................****************************...................................................
........................................................************.......................................................................................................................................................................................................******
Commands:
  rspec help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
  rspec My Batch          # This is my awesome batch
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Why the desc messages been shown here? How to config to remove them?

Comment: Thats how `Thor` works, it is unclear why you would launch `Thor` CLI and expect it not to work the way it works

Comment: If you do not want the description to be shown, do not define a description. It is not mandatory.

Comment: @WandMaker Because in my project, I should run a batch by hand and use some options.

Comment: @mudasobwa If I don't use it. My test will not past.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I'd imagine you could probably patch it out with something like:

```
module Thor
  def puts(*args, &block)
    # do nothing
  end
end
```

EDIT: actually it looks like this might be handled a little differently here: https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb

It looks like you could stub out `Thor::Shell::Basic#stdout` and `#stderr`

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I should rewrite Thor module?

Comment: It's not out of the ordinary to monkey patch out some methods in your libraries for testing. It adds a dependency to your code, but I find being able to test the functionality is usually worth it